# Libnotify: notify_register_coalesced_registration failed with code 9 on line 2835

Tags: macos, google-chrome, libnotify

I found the following message repeating repeating many many times (~5 times/minute) in the system.log on my `macos x`:

```
Apr  5 12:23:52 macbook-air Google Chrome Helper[8216]: 
Libnotify: notify_register_coalesced_registration failed with code 9 on line 2835
```

What does it mean? What can I do to fix it and stop having the messages in my log file?

Comment: Happens with Brave too

Comment: https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/108078536/google-chrome-helper-libnotify-notify-register-coalesced-registration-failed-with-code-9-on?hl=en

Comment: It helps a lot if you state what version(s) of MacOS and of Chrome/Chromium/ Brave. From looking at that bug report: Chrome/88.0.4324.182 - 108.x+ and more recent; MacOS 11.x

Answer (score 3):

This error message also happens with the Chromium browser, and when it was submitted as a bug to the Chromium team, the response from them was to tag it as "WontFix", since in their words "This is probably due to the sandbox [a macOS thing]. We don’t control this log message though, so there’s nothing we can do."

See:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1179114

As Arul said earlier/above, the only apparent "fix" for this error is to upgrade macOS to Monterey, for those people whose Macs can be upgraded.

Answer (score 1):

This problem appears to be fixed in macOS Monterey. I no longer see the message since the OS upgrade.

```
$ cat /var/log/system.log|grep Libnotify
```

Comment: Which is a bummer, for those among us that are unable to upgrade to Monterey because Apple declared our machines obsolete...